mysql max_connections equivalent in arangodb
In Mysql we can control the max client connection using max_connection param in .cnf file. How we can achieve the same in Arangodb.
In Arangodb server.maximal-threads was used to control the I/O operations. Whether the same value was used to client max connections ?
For example if server.maximal-threads was configured as 32, only concurrent 32 connections can be made at any time ?
I have the arangodb documentation But could not find a relevant information.
